# Array input without asking number of elements of array

Tags: c

```
int array[], n;

printf("Enter number of elements\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
  scanf("%d", &array[c]);
```

The above is the code I use to input values to an array, but is there a way to give input values to the array without asking the user to give input to the number of elements in the array ?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to put values into `array` without user input?

Comment: Have the user enter a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to indicate the end of the array. Allocate an initial array, and then grow the array with `realloc` as necessary, until the user enters the sentinel value.

Comment: I need to know number of elements in the array ("n") , so I can use it for the for loop to put values into array, is there a way that user can just give values to the array ?   I later need to sort that array also

Comment: @user3386109 Sentinels are handy, but not with an array of integers. Since every value is valid there is no good sentinel without limiting what can be stored. You could change it to an array of *pointers* to integers, then `NULL` is the sentinel.

Comment: @Schwern As far as ending the user input, the sentinel value could be the letter `q` to quit. Which is to say that the OP should check the return value from `scanf` and terminate the input when the return value is not 1. I didn't intend that the OP put the sentinel into the array itself. OTOH, it's quite often the case that an integer array is used to store natural numbers, i.e. non-negative numbers, so the value `-1` is a perfectly acceptable sentinel value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the two most common options are to use [`realloc` to resize the array as needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), aka a dynamically sized array, or to use a different data structure called a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). They have their advantages and disadvantages.

A linked list is a bunch of data nodes with connections to the next (and if it's a double-linked list the previous) node. Something like:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    Node *next;
} Node;
```

This makes it very easy to add new elements anywhere you want, even in the middle. But to go to the nth node requires walking the whole list.

---

The other option is to keep track of the size of your array and call [`realloc`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) when you need more space. `realloc` will grow the memory allocated to the array. It might have to do this by copying everything to a new memory location, so you don't want to do this too often; generally you allocate more than you need.

With the exception of a dynamic size, this has all the advantages and disadvantages of a regular array. But it still requires that you track the allocated size of the array and resize as necessary, so you'll need a struct to store the array, its size, and the size of its elements, and some functions to control access.

---

C does not have these as built ins. You can implement them yourself as an exercise, it is educational and any decent algorithms and data structures book will have exercises for them. But for production use I'd recommend using a 3rd party library as they'll be well documented, optimized, and tested. There's any number available, I'd recommend starting with [Gnome Lib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) as it provides a large number of missing C basics like hashes, regexes, queues, better string handling, trees...

- [Double Linked Lists](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html)
- [Single Linked Lists](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html)
- [Dynamic Arrays](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that dynamically allocates space for an array and extends it as necessary:

```
#define SIZE 16        // initial size of the array
...
size_t arraySize = 0;  // Number of elements allocated for array
size_t count = 0;      // Number of elements used

int *array = malloc( sizeof *array * SIZE ); // initial allocation
if ( array )
  arraySize = SIZE;
else
  // error allocating memory, handle as appropriate

while ( !done )
{
  if ( count == arraySize ) // we need to extend the array
  {
    int *tmp = realloc( array, sizeof *array * (2 * arraySize) ); // double the size
    if ( !tmp )
      // error extending array, handle as appropriate
    else
    {
      arraySize *= 2;
      array = tmp;
    }
  }
  array[count++] = new_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking for integers ask the user to enter a comma separated list of values as string.

Then you treat that string to get, validate and count all the values.

Comment: Comma's, or anything else actually.

Comment: Dynamic lists in C aren't so difficult that a work around is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to know if you can simply ask users to input data to fill your array without first determining the array size?

If this is indeed what you want, then simply the answer is no. In c, you must declare the size of the array before you are allowed to add data to it. However, there is a workaround of this issue using a structure.

You could define a structure like this:

```
#define BUFSIZE 1024
typedef struct dynamic_array {
  int buffer[BUFSIZE]; // or whatever initial size you want
  int current_index;   // the index where the next data element should be inserted
  int buffer_size;     // this will initially equal BUFSIZE but could change
} dynamic_array;
```

If you declare this structure, then you simply need to define functions to initialize your array, insert into your array, delete, search, etc. When you insert an element, you'll want to check to see if your current_index < BUFSIZE. The code outline for this would look like:

```
function insert(dynamic_array *arr, int data) {
  if (arr->current_index < BUFSIZE) {     //your buffer has space!
    // add element to array
  }
  else { 
    // create new array that is twice the size of the old array and copy the data from the old array to the new array.
  }
}
```

using this method or a similar one, you can simply insert data into your array via the dynamic_array structure without having to worry about adding too much data given the initial array size.

Comment: The array here is not dynamically sized, it's `BUFSIZE` sized, which is fixed at the time of compilation, wasteful of memory when it is not completely needed, and leaves you with a problem if the data to eventually be stored exceeds `BUFSIZE`.

Comment: If you filled in the `// create new array that is twice the size of the old array and copy the data from the old array to the new array` part this would be a much better answer. Hint: the answer is `realloc`. Also `arr->current_index < BUFSIZE` should be `arr->current_index < arr->buffer_size` else the reallocation won't be noticed. And `buffer_size` should be initialized to `BUFSIZE` but really it shouldn't be using a fixed constant at all or you'll waste a lot of memory.